# Contar registros de campos relacionados y mostrarlos en una vista

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Necesito saber cómo mostrar, en una vista el número de servicios realizados por municipio y que se muestre el nombre del municipio, no su id. Hay que tener en cuenta que en la tabla de servicios no hay municipios, sino poblaciones.

He estado viendo ejemplos, pero no encuentro ninguno para mostrar un campo relacionado.

Teniendo en cuenta la estructura que pongo más abajo, he añadido en el controlador de servicios (**ServeisController.php**), para visualizar la cantidad de servicios por población, lo siguiente:

```
$quantitatCadaPoblacio = $serveis->countBy(function($item) {return $item['idPoblacio'];});
```

Luego, en la vista, me muestra un array con las id y su correspondiente cantidad

```
<p>POBLACIONS: {{ $quantitatCadaPoblacio }}</p>
```

Algo similar a esto: `POBLACIONS: {"13":61,"11":836}` (está cortado porque es muy largo)

---

### **ESTRUCTURA**

*Los campos que intervienen son:*
de la tabla t_serveis: **idPoblacio**
de la tabla a_poblacions: **id**, **nom**, **idMunicipi**
de la tabla a_municipis: **id**, **nom**

*Las relaciones son:*
t_serveis.idPoblacio -> a_poblacions.id
a_poblacions.idMunicipi -> a_municipis.id

*Las relaciones en laravel:*
En modelo **TServei**:

```
public function a_poblacio(){
   return $this->belongsTo(APoblacio::class, 'idPoblacio');
}
```

En modelo **APoblacio**:

```
public function a_municipi(){
   return $this->belongsTo(AMunicipi::class, 'idMunicipi');
}

public function t_servei(){
   return $this->hasMany(TServei::class, 'idPoblacio');
}
```

En modelo **AMunicipi**:

```
public function a_poblacio()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(APoblacio::class, 'idMunicipi');
    }
public function t_servei()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            TServei::class,
            APoblacio::class,
            'a_poblacions.idMunicipi', //llave foránea en APoblacio
            't_serveis.idPoblacio', // llave foránea en TServei
            'id', // llave primaria en AMunicipi
            'id' // llave primaria en APoblacio
        );
    }
```

El método, en **ServeiController.php**:

```
$llistatServeis = TServei::where('data_E', null)->with('a_poblacio')->get();   

        $quantitatCadaAmbit = $llistatServeis->countBy(function($item) {return $item['idAmbit'];});
 
 return view('explotacio/explotacio')->with('llistatServeis',$llistatServeis)
->with('quantitatCadaMunicipi',$quantitatCadaMunicipi);
```

### Gracias.

### NOTA:

El código de la pregunta está modificada con la solución, así que si te pasa algo parecido puedes fijarte en dicho código porque funciona, gracias a la respuesta y varios comentarios de @BetaM.
@BetaM eres un crack!!

Comment: Venga, que al final lo consigo!! Muchas gracias @BetaM, sobre todo por tu paciencia, jeje. Y disculpas a los que se líen con el orden de los post y los comentarios. Soy algo novato en este sistema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con las relaciones actualmente definidas me parece no se puede, lo digo por que *Servicios* y *Municipios* no están conectados de forma directa.

Lo que puedes hacer es uso de una relación [tiene muchos a través de](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) donde:

- Defines en el modelo `AMunicipio` la relación tiene muchos a través de, donde:

  - Definimos como primer argumento el modelo destino o al que apuntamos
  - Como segundo argumento el modelo que usamos como puente o unión entre los 2 modelos extremos
- Usamos el método [`withCount`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) para el conteo de relaciones dadas

Modelo `AMunicipio`

```
class AMunicipio extends Model
{
    public function servicios()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
                                        TServicio::class, 
                                        APoblacion::class,
                                        'foreign_id', //llave foránea en APoblacion
                                        'foreign_id', // llave foránea en TServicio
                                        'id', // llave primaria en AMunicipio
                                        'id' // llave primaria en APoblacion
                                    );
    }
}
```

Y la consulta así:

```
$serviciosPorMunicipio = AMunicipio::withCount('servicios')->get();
```

- A partir del 3er. argumento no son estrictamente necesarios, si tus modelos siguen las convenciones marcadas de Eloquent, en caso contrario revisa el enlace provisto mas arriba para comprobar la configuración que debes llevar a cabo.
- Acá puedes leer sobre [las convenciones de Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) que también es algo que te ayudará