# Contar registros de campos relacionados según contenido de otro campo y mostrarlos en una vista

Tags: laravel, relaciones

En la estructura mostrada en este hilo:
[Contar registros de campos relacionados y mostrarlos en una vista](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/402015/contar-registros-de-campos-relacionados-y-mostrarlos-en-una-vista)

Si se observa en el controlador **ServeisController.php**, hay una variable llamada `$llistatServeis`, que contiene un listado con todos los servicios realizados donde el campo `'data_E'` (fecha de eliminación) es nulo. Este campo es usado para ocultar los servicios rellenando una fecha de eliminación, en vez de borrarlos. Los registros ocultados se consideran borrados.

Aunque he comprobado que esta consulta no es necesaria para contar los municipios, me vale para plantear lo que necesito saber.

Necesito saber cómo hacer que la consulta que se almacena en `$quantitatCadaMunicipi` **no cuente** los muncipios de los servicios borrados (aquellos registros de la tabla *'t_serveis'* que tienen fecha de borrado, en los que `'data_E'!=null`)

Por otro lado, los ámbitos de los servicios hago que se cuenten con otra consulta (debido a que la tabla de ámbitos sí está relacionada directamente con la tabla de servicios, aprovecho la relación creada en el modelo):

```
$quantitatCadaAmbit = AAmbit::withCount('t_servei')->get();
```

Relación `t_serveis.idAmbit->a_ambits.id*, en modelo **AAmbit** :

```
public function t_servei()
{
    return $this->hasMany(TServei::class, 'idAmbit');
}
```

En este caso, también necesitaría saber cómo le indico que **no** cuente los ámbitos de los registros de servicios borrados. (aquellos que tienen fecha de borrado o `'data_E'!=null`)

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: No sé por qué me corta el inicio del post. Que empieza con un saludo: Hola, en la estructura mostrada... Ya me pasó con el otro post al que hace referencia el link.

Comment: En esto: **En este caso, también necesitaría saber cómo le indico que no me cuente los ámbitos de los registros de servicios borrados. (aquellos en los que 'data_E'!=null)** es al revés no? es decir que no cuente donde la columna sea igual a null que es de hecho el valor que considera una fila como borrada, ¿cierto?

Comment: Te agradecería pudieras ser mas claro en tu pregunta para poder entenderla mejor, ya que al momento no me parece del todo clara

Comment: Ei @BetaM, de nuevo al rescate!!  ;-)) . Muchas gracias. Lo he aclarado, puntualizando que data_E es donde se almacena la fecha de borrado (ocultado), por lo tanto no debo contar los registros que tienen fecha de borrado (data_E!=null) Con las consultas indicadas para contar, no encuentro la manera de excluir los registros de la tabla servicios que tengan fecha en data_E. Espero que esté más claro.